# Pytest integration with JunitXML reports

Tags: python, junit, pytest

I have a problem with understanding how we can integrate pytest with junitxml. I need to add some details in my test cases like test suit name, test case name, associate with jira ticket. Additionally I need to have possibility to add the name for each test steps. for example I have log in case and my steps as below:

1.Type username
2.Type pass
3.Click login
4.Verify result.

How can I add these steps with junitxml library in pytest. I have tried to do like below but it is not working.

```
def test_login(record_property, record_xml_attribute):
    record_xml_attribute('CLICK STEP', '1st step')
    record_property("1st step", "clicking")
    assert 1 == 1
```

Comment: How are you executing pytest? Can you show post the created xml file?

Comment: This is the command which I am using for execution: python -m pytest -v -s --junitxml=result.xml -o junit_family="xunit1". Should I add something else directly here?

Comment: Are you sure that the test is actually run (since you are missing the path to your test file in the command) Your code works perfectly 'fine' (You still did not post the xml output that you are getting vs. what you are expecting) for me when I do: `python -m pytest -v -s --junitxml=result.xml -o junit_family=xunit1 test.py`